# Error in creating new project in Kdevelop

Tags: kdevelop

I am using Ubuntu 17.10. I installed Kdevelop for a C++ gaming project, but when I create a new project it's showing something like:

> Could not load project management plugin KDevCMakeManager.Check that the required programs are installed, or see console output for more information.

What can I do now?

Kdevelop version 5.1.2

[image: screenshot with popup error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the package `cmake`. This contains the CMake build system as used by most of the KDevelop example projects.

Comment: How does one install cmake?

Comment: Using `apt`, or your favourite GUI package manager.